# How can I use str.matches() if I want to match different cases?

Tags: java

I have the following Strings `B113AAA`, `SV54DDD`. I want to test any String based on this format `[LETTER{LETTER}][NUMBERNUMBER{NUMBER}][LETTERLETTERLETTER]`.

I put the second `{letter}` and third `{number}` because it is optional. I want to know if I can use regex to do this without any other condition statements(if). If the fisrt LETTER is `B` for example, there is no need for the second letter in `{}`, and if it is `B` I can have 3 Numbers in the middle. But if it is anything else than `B`, it must have 2 letter and 2 numbers ( `LETTERLETTER NUMBERNUMBER LETTER LETTER LETTER`). 
Thank you!

This works only for `BB1N`, for `B1N` doesnt work.

```
String x ="B1N";
if(x.matches("[A-Z]{2}[0-9][A-Z]"))
```

Comment: String x ="B111NNN";
  if(x.matches("[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{2,3}[A-Z]{3}")) , I want to make this match only if first group of letter has the dimension 1, I mean it can match with 3 digits only if I have first group with 1 letter, If I have 2 letter this should match only with 2 numbers in the second group

Answer (score 1):

You can use alternation because you want

> ((one letter and three numbers) or (two letters and two numbers)) and tree letters

so you can write this:

```
String regex = "([A-Z][0-9]{3}|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2})[A-Z]{3}";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("B123XXX", "BB123XXX","B12XXX", "BB12XXX","BB12XXXX");
for (String string : list) {
    System.out.println(string + " : " + string.matches(regex));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can have it as:

```java
String regex = "^((?:B\d{3})|(?:[AC-Z][A-Z]\d{2}))[A-Z]{3}$"
```

Then do your match as:

```java
String x = ... ; // Represents your string to be compared.
if(x.matches(regex))
```